# how to translate linq query to method calls

Tags: c#, linq, sprache

I'm trying to make a parser using [Sprache](https://github.com/sprache/sprache)
I'm using F#.  All the examples I've ever seen for the library use the Linq query syntax.  I tried to translate the linq to f# using the "query" computation expression, but I got lost there.

Here is a sample I've been using.

```
[TestClass]
public class tests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void test()
    {
        var input = "\"this is text\"";
        var content = Class1.Quoted.Parse(input);
        Assert.AreEqual("this is text", content);
    }
}
public class Class1
{
    public static readonly Parser<string> Quoted =
        (from open in Parse.Char('"')
         from content in Parse.CharExcept('"').Many().Text()
         from close in Parse.Char('"')
         select content);

    public static readonly Parser<string> Quoted2 =
        Parse.Char('"').SelectMany(open => 
        Parse.CharExcept('"').Many().Text(), ())
}
```

The obvious way to do it is to just translate the linq down to method calls, but I don't know how to do that.  I tried looking at ILSpy, but that left me a bit confused.

How does the Linq query look as direct method calls?

Comment: @Jashaszun I do.  I'm not an expert, but I'm competent.  What I don't know how to do is translate the linq query into method calls.  I also don't know how to translate the linq query into an F# query thing.  That's what I am asking in this question.

Comment: @phil That makes sense. Sorry I seem insulting.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi true.  I edited the question at the end.  Is that better?

Comment: @phil, okay, I probably misunderstood. Your question is all about LINQ method calls, not conversion to F#, right? If that's the case, you may want to reflect that in your title and make it more prominent in your question.

Comment: Do you have Resharper? Resharper can convert between LINQ query syntax and method calls.

Comment: @JerryFederspiel I do not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translating your example

```
(from open in Parse.Char('"')
from content in Parse.CharExcept('"').Many().Text()
from close in Parse.Char('"')
select content);
```

gives

```
(Parse.Char('"')
.SelectMany(open => Parse.CharExcept('"').Many().Text(), (open, content) => new {open, content})
.SelectMany(@t => Parse.Char('"'), (@t, close) => @t.content));
```

NB: Going to an approach more idiomatic to F# may be tricky because computation expressions don't seem to have an equivalent to the overload of SelectMany that C# LINQ syntax gets precompiled to (and that Sprache provides).